# Is there still a way to install xvfb on OSX 10.11.6,

Tags: java, tomcat, xvfb

I need to run xvfb-run on a OSX 10.11.6, under tomcat server.
When I run

```
> brew install xvfb
```

I get  the following :

```
Error: No available formula with the name "xvfb"
```

I have installed XQuartz which has an xvfb extension.

`$ xvfb` *remains silent and does not returns the prompt*

```
$ xvfb-run

-bash: xvfb-run: command not found
```

Comment: `xvfb-run` is a shell script. You can almost certainly copy it from another host. It might need a little editing.